# How to implement Back button functionality in android

Tags: android

I want to implement back button functionality without pressing any hard keys. For example using proximity sensor. when any object comes to near to proximity I want to get previous activity. How to implement this in android is it possible ?. my code is like this :

```
SensorEventListener accelerometerSensorEventListener
        = new SensorEventListener(){

            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){              

                     finish();                  
                }

            }

     };
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
//On Back Pressed 

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        // do something on back.
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}strong text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    Log.d("CDA", "onBackPressed Called"); 
}
```

or

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    // do something on back.
    return true;
}
   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

inside the listener of the sensor, you may finish() the current activity. so it goes back to the caller activity.

Comment: Yes I tried it but it is not working. I will edit and post my code plz check it

Comment: can you try this:
    Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,
           CallerActivity.class);
         i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         startActivity(i);

Answer (score 0):

You can call [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29).

Comment: Have you registered your listener?